# Dell Poweredge 2900 - Raid 10 - 7 Disks - 3 failed - Am i screwed?

Tags: raid, drive-failure

Just want to know how screwed I am, I have Dell Poweredge 2900 running Raid 10 - 7 disks and 3 have failed.

Edit: I'm blind. There are a total of 8 disks and from I can see 3 have failed.

Here some pics:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g9GAL.jpg)

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/taElg.jpg)

[3][3]

Comment: It looks like you have 2 that have failed not 3 and we can't possibly tell without knowing the array layout.

Comment: pic shows two disks have failed. and RAID10 needs even number of disks. how did you configure RAID on this? can you show the RAID volume details?

Comment: This is a poorly written question of poor quality. What's more, you didn't take the time to look closely at your configuration to determine it's status. You have 8 disks, not 7. 2 of the 8 disks are in a failed state. The array is in a degraded state, but not in a failed state. How screwed are you? Your array is still intact but you need to replace the failed drives so that the array can rebuild them.

Comment: Well, the commenters are right of course, it's a bad question...but doesn't the image show 3 failed disks? 00, 03 and 06? Also: PD count=5 (of 8)?

Comment: My bad, there are 3 failed disks out of 8.

Comment: Sorry for being a noob. How would I show you the volume details ?

Answer (score 3):

When you say "how screwed I am", is the system/array actually non functional?
The second screenshot shows "Degraded", which usually means the array has failed devices but still has enough devices to work.

RAID10 is effectively lots of mirrors, so you can lose half the disks without the array failing - so long as each failed disk is part of a different mirror. If you lose two disks in the same mirror then obviously that mirror is dead, and so is the overall array.

It's rare that 3 fail at the same time of course, which suggests these failures may have happened over a longer period of time and not been monitored.

If the array really is just degraded then you should be able to get new disks (ASAP) and rebuild it.

If the array is non-functional though (such as the machine not booting if the array contains the OS, or the array not working inside the OS), then there may be corruption and you'd probably be better off rebuilding from scratch and restoring backups.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Server is not booting into ESXi. Its like it doesn't find anything to boot from.